# How to load the content of a named list into global environment?

Tags: r, list, environment

Suppose I have a named list `x`:

```
x <- list(a = 1, b = 2)
```

How can I load the content of `x` into the global environment so that I can access `a` and `b` from the global environment?:

```
a
# [1] 1
b
# [2] 2
```

(why I do this: in reality, the `x` is derived from a `.mat` file produced by matlab. It's more like an `.Rdata` file)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use `list2env`

```
list2env(x, .GlobalEnv)
a
#[1] 1
b
#[1] 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use attach(x) to make a and b available in the search list.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).